# Remove a portion of php variable output

Tags: php, jquery

I have following php:

```
$my_name = $my_site->getUserData("dfd_Name");

<?php echo $my_name?>
```

It outputs as following:  `Steve, Kim`

I want to keep the format as it is. However there are times when I only need the first part (for example, "`steve`").

Is there a jquery way to remove everything after (including "`,`") the comma, so it will be "`Steve`" as the output.

**EDIT**

So, I am using the following php:

```
<a class="my_name_class" href="http://example.com/section1/section2/section3/<?php echo $my_name ?>" >
  <?php echo esc_html($my_name) ; ?>                            
</a>
```

What would be the jQuery (or any other ways) to remove the second part (`, kim`) within the href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick solution in pure jQuery

HTML:

```
<span class="name">Steve, Kim</span>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".name").text($(".name").text().split(',')[0]);
});
```

To get the second part, change the above code to:

```
$(function () {
    $(".name").text($(".name").text().split(',')[1]);
});
```

Include jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/myLnnd0e/

Showing second name: https://jsfiddle.net/myLnnd0e/1/

Fixed for URL: https://jsfiddle.net/myLnnd0e/3/

---

Solution for URL:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://http://example.com/section1/section2/section3/" data-names="Steve, Kim" class="name-url">http://example.com/section1/section2/section3/</a>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $(".name-url").attr("href", ($(".name-url").attr("href") + $(".name-url").data("names").split(',')[1].trim())).append($(".name-url").data("names").split(',')[1].trim());
});
```

---

While this is a completely valid use of Javascript, it is always best to provide users with an alternate way to access this data, for usability issues and also in the case that Javascript is disabled.

Comment: Hi. So, I realized that when I put the variable within the href, it does not work properly. I edited my question. What would be the proper way to target the second part (, kim) within the href?

Comment: @steveKim Hi, I have updated my answer to reflect your updated question! Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you. So, I just realized that I didn't write my question properly. I meant to remove the second par (, kim) when it is in the url. Like I have a very specific url (http://example.com/section1/section2/section3/<?php echo $my_name ?>). With the original jQuery, it does not really work as now there are more texts. So, I was wondering if you know how I can remove the second part (, kim) in this very specific url structure.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. :P

Comment: @steveKim Sure! Give me one second.

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new today. Really appreciate it. Hope you have a great day! =)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP,

```
<?php echo explode(',', $my_name)[0]?>
```

---

In jQuery,

First select that DOM part,

```
var thing = $('#anything').html();
```

and explode like,

```
var name = thing.split(',');
```

Your desired value,

```
name[0];
```

Place it in DOM like,

```
thing.html(name[0]);
```

Comment: Hi. So, I realized that when I put the variable within the href, it does not work properly. I edited my question. What would be the proper way to target the second part (, kim) within the href?